# How to resolve Path Traversal vulnerability for the below code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blobstore, multer-s3

```
const downloadFile = blobstoreRouter.get('/blobstore/download/:filename', (req, res) => {
var localFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', escape(req.params.filename));
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(localFile);
try {
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        Key: req.params.filename
    }).createReadStream().pipe(file);
    fs.readdir('src', (_err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file);
            logger.info(file);
        });
    });
    res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security',
    'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains');
    res.sendFile(file);
} catch (err) {
    logger.error('Error downloading the file ' + err);
    res.send('Failed');
}
});
```

Checkmarx gives warning at the line
res.sendFile(file);

I've added the HSTS header also for the same but not sure if that works as well. Please guide me through both. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Neither adding HSTS or escaping the req.params.filename will mitigate the Path Traversal vulnerability. To understand what Path Traversal is, here's a blog post that you might want to read:

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/security/introduction/

There are plenty of ways to resolve this security finding, but Checkmarx recognizes the use of sanitization methods such as [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Remove potentially malicious characters that will allow an attacker to traverse on different paths of your S3 bucket:

```
var localFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', escape(req.params.filename.replace(/^(\.\.(\/|\\|$))+/, '')));
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(localFile);
try {
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        Key: req.params.filename.replace(/^(\.\.(\/|\\|$))+/, '')
    }).createReadStream().pipe(file);
    fs.readdir('src', (_err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file);
            logger.info(file);
        });
    });
```